# Allowing execution of binary file from PHP web app (SELinux)

Tags: php, apache, centos, selinux

I want to run a binary say, ./blastn (which is inside a bin directory within the doc root of the web app) from my PHP web application. I have used PHP function exec() for this as below:

```
exec("echo -e {$input_seq} | ./blastn -db XXXX_NT",$cmd_output,$cmd_status);
```

When I try to run, it gives the return status 126 and the following error message in the logs

> sh: line 13: ./blastn: Permission denied

It executes when I set the sebool httpd_unified to 1. Is it possible to do this without setting this SELinux bool.

> System details : Apache 2.4.6 on Centos 7, PHP 7.3.12

Comment: Sure, you have to adjust the policy. The "audit" logs from the kernel might help.

Comment: The problem is that I have checked both /var/log/messages and /var/log/audit/audit.log and there are no messages in these. The only error message I see is "sh: line 13: ./blastn: Permission denied" in the error log of Apache. Earlier, I had adjusted the policy for executing blastn similarly (/usr/bin/blastn) using the command: ausearch -m AVC --comm blast | audit2allow -M my-blast. But here I am trying to execute the same program blastn whose binary file is located within the docroot of Apache.

Comment: If there is just "permission denied", but no SELinux audit message, then it's the DAC permission, i.e. owner and "chmod" permissions